# WebSocket сервер на C#

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

Требуется написать `WebSocket` сервер. Сначала я попробовал использовать `Socket` и получил много проблем: `handshake`, декодирование данных и т.д. Стал искать что-нибудь готовое, узнал, что в `.net` есть `System.Net.WebSockets`, стал разбираться и ничего не понятно. Кто-нибудь знает как им пользоваться без использования `asp`? Может примерчик какой-нибудь...гугл не помогает.

Comment: Это немного не то. Мне нужно работать именно с WebSocket протоколом.

Comment: А, понял, тогда не то.

Comment: а что конкретно не получается с _System.Net.WebSockets_?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnikov посмотрите SignalR. подробнее [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/477285/4).

Comment: @SergeyKolesnikov _"без использования asp"_ -- есть замена, называется OWIN. описание и примеры есть [тут](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana)

Comment: На Win7 не поддерживаются сокеты в .net.

Answer (score 1):

Готовая реализация декодирования фреймов WebSocket обсуждалась в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/854206/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-websocket-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/854207#854207). Если вас интересует всё решение, внизу есть ссылка. В нем так же есть рукопожатие, декодирование сообщений для клиента - это полностью работающий сервер WebSocket