# Реализация протокола WebSocket на C#

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, .net-core, реализация

На GitHub есть репозиторий с [реализацией](https://github.com/harshalshahg/WebSocket/blob/master/WebSocketSimplified/Server/WebSocketServer.cs) декодирования фреймов протокола WebSocket. Проблема в том, что если в один момент времени отправляется много сообщений, браузер склеивает фреймы и код работает некоректно

```
private String DecodeMessageFromClient(Byte[] bytes)
{
    try
    {
        String incomingData = String.Empty;
        Byte secondByte = bytes[1];

        Int32 dataLength = secondByte & 127;
        Int32 indexFirstMask = 2;

        if (dataLength == 126) indexFirstMask = 4;
        else if (dataLength == 127) indexFirstMask = 10;

        IEnumerable<Byte> keys = bytes.Skip(indexFirstMask).Take(4);
        Int32 indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4;

        Byte[] decoded = new Byte[bytes.Length - indexFirstDataByte];
        for (Int32 i = indexFirstDataByte, j = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++, j++)
        {
            decoded[j] = (Byte)(bytes[i] ^ keys.ElementAt(j % 4));
        }

        return incomingData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Could not decode due to :" + ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходя из названий переменных, происходит это по тому, что код пропускает заголовок, а остальную информацию считает за содержимое фрейма. Но так как в сообщении два фрейма, второй заголовок не пропускается.

```
for (Int32 i = indexFirstDataByte, j = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++, j++)
```

Comment: Это не браузер склеивает фреймы, это протокол TCP так работает вообще-то...

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну вот браузер и отправляет два фрейма вместе, без задержки между ними. По протоколу TCP. Поэтому stream.DataAvailable не переключается на false и байты из двух фреймов оказываются в одном массиве

Comment: Вы так пишите, как будто фреймы отправленные с задержкой не могут склеиться друг с другом! А они склеятся при любом сетевом лаге.

Comment: @PavelMayorov с задержкой этот код не заработает, верно. Но это исправление реализации, мне нужно было с веб страницы, запущенной локально, получать данные в реальном времени.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Новый код сложнее. Он получает массив байт, выделяет от туда первый фрейм и возвращает оставшиеся байты, не участвующие в декодировании

```
public static byte[] WebSocketBackendMessage(this NetworkStream stream,byte[] bytes,out string message,out WebSocketMessageType type)
{
    byte oppcode = bytes[0];
    byte shift = 15;
    type = (WebSocketMessageType)(oppcode & shift);

    String incomingData = String.Empty;
    Byte secondByte = bytes[1];
    Int32 dataLength = secondByte & 127;
    Int32 indexFirstMask = 2;
    if (dataLength == 126)
    {
        indexFirstMask = 4;
        byte[] newlenght = bytes.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray();
        Array.Reverse(newlenght);
        dataLength = BitConverter.ToUInt16(newlenght, 0);
    }
    else if (dataLength == 127)
    {
        indexFirstMask = 10;
        throw new Exception("Слишком большой массив информации был отправлен на вебсокет!");
    }
    IEnumerable<Byte> keys = bytes.Skip(indexFirstMask).Take(4);
    Int32 indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4;

    Byte[] decoded = new Byte[bytes.Length - indexFirstDataByte];
    for (Int32 i = indexFirstDataByte, j = 0; i < indexFirstDataByte + dataLength; i++, j++)
    {
        decoded[j] = (Byte)(bytes[i] ^ keys.ElementAt(j % 4));
    }

    message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);

    byte[] remain = bytes.Skip(indexFirstDataByte + dataLength).ToArray();
    if (remain.Length == 0) return null;
    else return remain;
}
```

Используется он так:

```
byte[] block = stream.ReadBlock();
string message = null;
WebSocketMessageType type;

bool lastFrameEmpty = false;
while(!lastFrameEmpty)
{
    lastFrameEmpty = (block = stream.WebSocketBackendMessage(block, out message,out type)) == null;
    if (type == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE: {0}", message);
    }
    if (type == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
    {
        continueWorking = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

На всякий случай, прикреплю код расширения, считывающего блок информации, полученный от браузера

```
public static byte[] ReadBlock(this NetworkStream stream)
{
    Byte[] bytes = null;

    using (MemoryStream tmp = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1];
        int readed = -1;
        while (stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            readed = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            tmp.Write(data, 0, readed);
        }
        if (readed > -1)
        {
            bytes = tmp.ToArray();
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Вы можете скачать решение для Visual Studio по ссылке: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/KEeF/H81Q22MXP

Comment: Слишком сложно все. Почему бы просто не прочитать из потока сначала заголовок, а потом уже сообщение известной длины?

Comment: @PavelMayorov чтение в реальном времени будет определенно сложнее. Этот код есть исправление реализации, ссылка на которую в вопросе

Comment: Нет, это будет проще. Код останется тот же самый, только исчезнет лишняя работа с массивами и метод ReadBlock.

Comment: @PavelMayorov сделайте правильную реализацию и предложите в ответы